# Autofilter empty most of the data of my sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter data according to a criteria.

The data data I want to filter are in the columns B to F. In column F I have integer values, 2, 4, 8,... etc.

The row with the filters are in the row 13, above I have a header of the document.

The filter that I am trying to use is  this:

```
Me.Range("F13").AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:="8", _
    VisibleDropDown:=False
```

But this empty most of the data of the sheet.

Why most of the data is filtered?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't use `"8"`, but `8`.

Comment: Although I use 8 instead of "8", I get the same result, all data that is under row 13th is hidden.

Comment: Unable to reproduce: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHMLH.png. Is there something different about the data in F?

Comment: You should record a macro of you applying the correct filters and go from there.